# What is the best way to send emails via c# using O365 domain?

Tags: c#, office365

I am trying to use the code snippet below. The goal is to just send an email, however I am getting an error *"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated."*.

My question is. What is the best way to send emails via code if an SMPT server requires an authenticated account? Is it bad practice to have a developer type account created for this purpose?

```
string server = "";
string to = "";
string from = "";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message. Subject = "Subject";
message. Body = "Body";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client. Port = 000;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I send email using `System.Net.Mail` through office365 smtp.

Yes, you need to have an account and password with office365 to be able to send email through their smtp server. Use the code below, it is the same one I use in my web app to send email to users.

```
using (var message = new MailMessage())
{
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recepient email", "receipient name"));
    message.From = new MailAddress("your email", "your name");
    message.Subject = "My subject";
    message.Body = "My message";
    message.IsBodyHtml = false; // change to true if body msg is in html

    using (var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com"))
    {
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your email", "your password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(message); // Email sent
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Email not sent, log exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that having your credentials for any account stored in your source code in plain text is a security red flag. Using encrypted credentials, or even better, running the code under an account that has email privileges in O365 are more secure and less likely to come back to bite you in the future.

Comment: @Logarr, in this  code I show as plain text so that the reader understands what is expected. It is easier to understand this way. However, regarding security and why you must not hardcode your credentials, that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Identifying dangerous practices in example code may be technically out of scope, but just as the folks on SuperUser will not recommend recrusive wildcard deletions in Linux without disclaimers, we should not offer up vulnerable code to the uninformed.

Comment: @Ibrahim and Logarr Thank you both. I did assume that Ibrahim was keeping the credentials in plain text for example purposes. Additionally Logarr, your suggestion of trying to run the program as an authenticated user very helpful.

Comment: @Ibrahim The part of your answer that is most helpful to me is the confirming that having a dedicated user created in O365 is the best approach.